How can I change the extremes of a modular function in a double integral?
So I have to find $ \iint_R|y-x^2|\,dy \,dx$, where $R = [0,1] \times [0,1]$.
I know we are going to have two cases
$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} y-x^2, y-x^2 \geq 0 \\ x^2-y, y-x^2 < 0 &\end{cases}$
But I'm struggling on how we are going "split" into two double integral and analyze the new extremes of it.

Do you know how to integrate over curved regions? Because the rectangle can be divided into two curved regions. On each of them the integrand can be written without the absolute value.

We can split this into two integrals. Both integrals will be from $x=0$ to $x=1$. However, one integral will be from $y=0$ to $y=x^2$ and the other will be from $y=x^2$ to $y=1$. We can see the first integral is where $y<x^2$ so we should have $x^2-y$ as our integrand. Similarly, our second integral represents the region where $y > x^2$ so our integrand will be $y-x^2$. We can now write this out and it becomes much simpler to solve:
$$ \int\int_R |y-x^2| dydx = \int_0^1\int_0^{x^2} (x^2-y) dydx + \int_0^1\int_{x^2}^1 (y-x^2)dydx $$
$$ = \int_0^1 \left(x^2y - \frac{y^2}{2}\right)^{y=x^2}_{y=0} dx + \int_0^1\left(\frac{y^2}{2} - x^2y\right)_{y=x^2}^{y=1} dx $$
$$ = \int_0^1  \left(x^4-\frac{x^4}{2}\right) dx + \int_0^1 \left(\frac{1}{2} - x^2 - \frac{x^4}{2} + x^4 \right) dx$$
Because these integrals are over the same region, with respect to the same variable we can combine them and get:
$$ = \int_0^1 x^4 - x^2 + \frac{1}{2} $$
$$ = \left( \frac{x^5}{5} - \frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{x}{2} \right)_{x=0}^{x=1} $$
$$ = \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{2} = \frac{11}{30} $$

You can split the square in two regions: One below the parabola and another above the parabola:
$$
\int_0^1 \int_0^1 f(x,y) dx dy = \int_0^1 \int_0^{x^2} f(x,y) dy dx + \int_0^1
\int_{x^2}^1 f(x,y) dy dx$$
Now, you just need to replace $f$ by the appropriate expression in each case.
